# mocha nyc and source maps

Tags: typescript, mocha.js, source-maps, nyc

So. I am trying to get my head around why this isn't working.

I am writing source and test TypeScript code in files in the `src` and `tests` directory. These are `*.ts` and `*.spec.ts` files.

I use `npx tsc` to transpile both the source and test files to the directory `build`. So this directory now contains `*.js.`, `*.spec.js`, `*.js.map` and `*.spec.js.map` file types.

***How do I setup mocha and nyc to work with this now?***

I have the following set.

.nycrc.json

```
{
    "extends": "@istanbuljs/nyc-config-typescript",
    "all": true,
    "branches": 0,
    "lines": 0,
    "functions": 0,
    "statements": 0,
    "check-coverage": true,
    "exclude": [".ignore", "coverage"],
    "report-dir": "./coverage/",
    "cache": false,
    "source-map": true,
    "produce-source-map": true
}
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "allowJs": true,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "strictNullChecks": true,
        "noImplicitThis": true,
        "alwaysStrict": true,
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es2016",
        "lib": ["es2016"],
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "types": ["mocha", "node"],
        "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"],
        "sourceMap": true,
        "outDir": "./build/",
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "removeComments": false
    },
    "include": ["./**/*.ts", "./**/*.js"]
}
```

Error:

```
karl@karl-Dell-Precision-M3800:~/dev/escd$ NODE_ENV=test npx nyc --reporter=html --reporter=text mocha "./build/tests/**/*.js"
mappedCoverage.addStatement is not a function
```

However if I set `all` to `false` in the `.nycrc.json` file, then it doesn't complain. What's up?

I do not wish to use `ts-node` or anything similar, I have already transpiled the files.

Comment: I gave a detailed example on this other post here, it might be a duplicate:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/64829161/2538750

This seems to be the same reason (nyc is not configured properly for typescript. The settings can be tricky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/istanbuljs/nyc#source-map-support-for-pre-instrumented-codebases

I had to remove `"extends": "@istanbuljs/nyc-config-typescript",` and add     `"exclude-after-remap": false,`.